# Cannot import AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

Does anybody know why I cannot seem to utilize the AudioKit framework in my code?  I have added the framework to my project, but When I try to import AudioKit, I just get "No such module AudioKit."  I have a fully updated version of Xcode and see that people online have had similar issues, but I cannot find a solution other than those related to the use of Playgrounds (I am not using a Playground).

Comment: Probably the answer is in this thread: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/525 or https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/343

Answer (score 1):

Eric George did a nice write up of our screenshare together on this topic:

[Referenced AudioKit framework is not recognized by XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273149/referenced-audiokit-framework-is-not-recognized-by-xcode)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Step 3 of his solution is what I have been missing.  However, the module is still not found after I have gone into build settings, then Framework Search Paths, and specified "$(SRCROOT)/" for the project and "$(inherited)" for the targets.  Also, the framework search path for my project ends up being /Users/.../"PROJECT NAME"/ instead of $(SRCROOT)/../../_Libraries/AudioKit-iOS.  Not sure if I'm following the process correctly as I have never added frameworks to Xcode before.

Comment: What it displays differs from what is actually in the text field.  It's showing the expanded version but if you double click to edit it I bet SRCROOT will be back.

Comment: Ah yes, that is the case. I just wasn't sure if it should have been ending up with /AudioKit-iOS.  Any suggestions on why I still am not able to import AudioKit though?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Start with a new project and step us through exactly what you do to set it up.  Maybe we can find the issue then.

Comment: Its bound to be some detail that's hard to find from descriptions. I'd offer you a screenshare if you want to reach out via email.

Comment: Sure, that would be extremely helpful!  At what email address should I contact you?